# Java reading a vector from a txt file gives error

Tags: java, vector, compiler-errors

i am trying to write and read a vector to a text file. I made a class WriteVectorToFile (shown below) which makes a vector containing objects of a class called Car. The class Car implements Serializable and only contains information with setter and getter methods. In the WriteVectorToFile class i have made a createVector() method and writetoFile() method and they work. The problem in the readtoFile() method and it gives out an error (listed below). I want to know what am i doing wrong and what is causing the problem.

```
The error :
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WriteVectorToFile.readtoFile(WriteVectorToFile.java:73)
    at WriteVectorToFile.main(WriteVectorToFile.java:110)
    at __SHELL1.run(__SHELL1.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class WriteVectorToFile{

    private Car car1; 
    private Vector garage;
    private File myFile;
    private FileOutputStream out;
    private FileInputStream in;
    private ObjectInputStream objin;
    private ObjectOutputStream objout;

  public WriteVectorToFile(){

      this.myFile = new File("E:/JAVA/My Java Programs/MyVectorFile.txt");

      try{
        myFile.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("New File --> Success.");
      }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("New File --> Fail.");
      }   

    }

    private void writetoFile(){
       try{
           out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
           objout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){ 
           e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
         objout.writeObject(garage);
         objout.close();
         System.out.println("Write File --> Success.");
       }catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println("Write File --> Fail.");
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void readtoFile(){
       try{
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
         ObjectInputStream objin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
       }catch(FileNotFoundException e){ 
          e.printStackTrace();
       }catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }

       // Object obj = null;
       Vector tempVec = new Vector();

       try{ 

    ERROR Line 73 : tempVec = (Vector) objin.readObject(); 
          objin.close();
          System.out.println("Read File --> Success.");

        }catch(Exception e){

          System.out.println("Read File --> Fail.");
          e.printStackTrace();

        }

       //Car tempg = new Car();
       //tempg = (Car) vecNew.firstElement();

       //System.out.println(tempg.toString());
       //System.out.println(((Car)(vecNew.firstElement())).toString());

    }

    private void createVector(){

       this.garage = new Vector();
       // To create a vector with a specific datatype add <type>
       // Vector garage = new Vector<Car>();

       car1 = new Car("3245","Toyota","Ferry23",(double)34500);
       this.garage.add(car1);
       this.garage.add(new Car("3232","Fiat","MozoZ3",(double)25000));
       this.garage.add(new Car("2345","Mazda","ZenFix",(double)13700));

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

       WriteVectorToFile test = new WriteVectorToFile();
       test.createVector();
       test.writetoFile();
       test.readtoFile();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, apologies as I cannot post it as comment so putting it into an answer block:

Your problem is the scope mismatch involving try-catch blocks . If you have done any C++, the objects are passed by value or reference so this could have been avoided very conveniently. But Java passes everything by value so when you do:

```
   try{
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
     ObjectInputStream objin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){ 
      e.printStackTrace();
   }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The object `objin` is created inside try-catch scope which is *NOT* the same when you use it in:

```
tempVec = (Vector) objin.readObject(); 
      objin.close();
      System.out.println("Read File --> Success.");

    }catch(Exception e){

      System.out.println("Read File --> Fail.");
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

So the solution is put everything in one "try" block and catch all the exceptions seperately (or even together using Exception as superclass [not a good practice]). This should do the job. Tell us if you manage to solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined the  `private ObjectInputStream objin;` as instance variable and it is `null`. So when you invoke `objin.readObject();` on `null` will throw `NullPointerException`. Inside the `readtoFile()` method, you do something like this:

```
try{
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
     ObjectInputStream objin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){ 
      e.printStackTrace();
   }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

That defines a new local `ObjectInputStream objin = new ObjectInputStream(in);` inside try block, which is invisible to the code `tempVec = (Vector) objin.readObject();` ouside try-catch block. Here `objin` refers to the instance variable declared at instance level and it is `null`. To correct it change

```
ObjectInputStream objin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
```

to

```
objin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
```

inside the try block.